# Function triggers in If condition

Tags: php

I have a function that triggers from an if statement which checks if a template is valid. At the end I've put an if to check if the aformentioned function has collected any data, if yes it returns TRUE.

When I do an if within the if to see if loop() has returned true it triggers again and I have the information taken two times. How do I prevent this?

I tried using a boolean in global scope that is updated through the if  in loop() but I couldn't get it to update.

loop() function:

```
for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) { // START FROM ROW 2 TO AVOID TEMPLATE
    for ($col = 1; $col <= $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) { // START FROM COLUMN A
        $value = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();
        // SORTING INTO CORRECT ARRAYS
        if ($col == 1){
          $ids[] = $value;
        };
        if ($col == 2){
          $names[] = $value;
        };
        if ($col == 3){
          $ages[] = $value;
        };
    }
  }
  if (!empty($ids) && !empty($names) && !empty($ages)){
    return TRUE;
  };
```

The if statement:

```
if ($idTemplate == "ID" && $nameTemplate == "NAME" && $ageTemplate == "AGE"){
  loop();
  if (loop() == TRUE){
    addSQL();
  }
};
```

I'm expecting loop() not to run two times and to have it confirmed that it's actually working so addSQL() runs

Comment: why would you not expect it to run twice? You call it twice..

Comment: Why does it activate in the if (loop() == TRUE) ?

Comment: Because `loop()` _is_ a function call.

Comment: just remove the line `loop();`

Comment: **Side note:** Why a semicolon after the brace?

Comment: Okay, then how do I check if the function returns true? I tried adding a global boolean that changes from FALSE to TRUE inside the loop() if, but I couldn't get it to change. Tried it with 0 and 1 as well and no result.

Comment: Or just go with `if ($idTemplate == "ID" && $nameTemplate == "NAME" && $ageTemplate == "AGE" && loop() ) { addSQL(); } }` in the first place …

Comment: @vivek_23 idk just used to putting }; after last if /else statements

Comment: _“Okay, then how do I check if the function returns true?”_ – that is what `if (loop() == TRUE)` _already_ does. Just remove the extra call _before_ the `if` then, if you don’t want to call the function twice …?

Comment: `code if (loop() == TRUE){
    addSQL();
  } ` @misorude

Comment: Was that supposed to be a question, some kind of statement, or … what?

Comment: @morskiq123 wrapping a function call in a conditional doesn't prevent the function being called. Store the loop function output to a var and compare against the variable - not the function. Or just skip the first function call and do `if (loop())` whatever your preference

Comment: @treyBake Yeah, I did that but the problem was I couldn't change the value of the variable. I put the variable that is supposed to change in the if statement of loop(), though it couldn't change. It works if I `code do if loop() == TRUE{ addSQL(); };`